# How to search thru Core Data entities and delete certain objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios, nspredicate

I'm unclear how to remove certain objects from Core Data database. I think I've got it working so I can find the objects, but don't know how to delete them from Core Data. In this example I'm searching the entity News for items which have expired. I use the 'expires' property (an int 32 unix time stamp) and see if the number is less than the current unix time stamp. Not sure if the NSPredicate is right in this.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity]; 

// Set up predicate here?
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"expires < %i", dateInt]; // dateInt is a unix time stamp for the current time
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"forename" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy] autorelease];
[request release];

// delete the found objects here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `-[NSManagedObjectContext deleteObject:]` for every object you want to delete, then commit the changes.

Comment: Do you mean I step thru the mutableFetchResults array and [managedObjectContext deleteObject:mutableFetchResultsItem] for each item in the array?

Comment: Yes. There is no convenience method to delete an entire array at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NSBatchDeleteRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html) available on `iOS 9.0+`, `macOS 10.11+`, `tvOS 9.0+`, `watchOS 2.0+`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"expires < %i", dateInt];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [News fetchRequest];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
// Create batch delete request
NSBatchDeleteRequest *deleteReq = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest];
NSError *error = nil;
NSBatchDeleteResult *deletedResult = [appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext executeRequest:deleteReq error:&error];
if (error) {
  NSLog(@"Unable to delete the data");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"%@ deleted", deleteReq.result);
}
```

---

Swift code (from the above link)

```
let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Employee")
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "terminationDate < %@", NSDate())
let request = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetch)

do {
    let result = try moc.execute(request)
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to execute request: \(error)")
}
```

---

#### NOTE:

I found below comment about `execute` of `moc`

> Method to pass a request to the store without affecting the contents of the managed object context.

Which means any unsaved data in `moc` won't be affected. i.e. if you've created/updated entity that falls in the delete request criteria and don't called `save` on `moc` then that object won't be deleted.